# Ansible: Not able to get AMI ID of newly created AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am using a playbook to create ami and trying to fetch the newly created ami id. But the debug is getting 'msg": "AMI not updated"'' Please help

---

```
- name: Create AMI
  ec2_ami:
    region: "{{ec2_region}}"
    name: "aws-{{ec2_region}}"
    state: present
    instance_id: "{{ec2_info.instances.0.id}}"
    wait: yes
    tags:
       Name: "aws-{{ec2_region}}-mr-ami"
       deployment_type: "{{deployment_type}}"
       pop_type: "{{pop_type}}"
  register: image

- pause:
    seconds: 10

- debug:
    msg: "{{image}}"

- name: Set image id as fact
  set_fact:
      mr_ami_id: "{{image.image_id}}"
```

---

Playbook output

TASK [Create AMI]
*************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "aws_access_key": null,
            "aws_secret_key": null,
            "delete_snapshot": false,
            "description": "",
            "device_mapping": null,
            "ec2_url": null,
            "image_id": null,
            "instance_id": "i-065404d0d37e0acfb",
            "kernel_id": null,
            "launch_permissions": null,
            "name": "aws-ap-southeast-2-MessageRelay",
            "no_reboot": false,
            "profile": null,
            "region": "ap-southeast-2",
            "root_device_name": null,
            "security_token": null,
            "state": "present",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "aws-ap-southeast-2-mr-ami",
                "deployment_type": "dev",
                "pop_type": "mgmt"
            },
            "validate_certs": true,
            "virtualization_type": "hvm",
            "wait": true,
            "wait_timeout": "900"
        }
    },
    "launch_permissions": {},
    "msg": "AMI not updated" }

TASK [pause]
******************************************************************************************************************************** task path: /root/*********************/create_ami.yml:24 Pausing for 10 seconds (ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort) ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "delta": 10,
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2017-08-01 08:48:29.756546",
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "Paused for 10.0 seconds",
    "stop": "2017-08-01 08:48:39.756843",
    "user_input": "" }

TASK [debug]
******************************************************************************************************************************** task path: /root/*****************/create_ami.yml:27 ok: [localhost]
=> {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "launch_permissions": {},
        "msg": "AMI not updated"
    } }

TASK [Set image id as fact]
***************************************************************************************************************** task path: /root/***********/trunk/ncs/pop-deployment/********_asg/tasks/create_ami.yml:30 fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'image_id'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/**************************/create_ami.yml': line 30, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Set image id as fact\n  ^ here\n" }

PLAY RECAP
********************************************************************************************************************************** ip-10-10-5-111.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal : ok=13   changed=9    unreachable=0    failed=0 localhost                  : ok=69   changed=31   unreachable=0    failed=1

Comment: Are you sure the `AMI` is getting created? Can you check in AWS console?

Comment: @helloV , This was happening because AMI with name "aws-{{ec2_region}}" was already there and hence no new ami was getting created. I deleted the old AMI and ran the playbook again without any issues. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because AMI with name "aws-{{ec2_region}}" was already there and hence no new ami was getting created. I deleted the old AMI and ran the playbook again without any issues.